# How to load OpenStreatMap dump to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, import, imposm

I found tool named [imposm](https://imposm.org/docs/imposm3/latest/), I want to make local copy of OSM data and load them to PostgreSQL.

I can't understand how to do it. I run it with follow command:
`imposm3 run -config /apps/imposm/config.json`

Config is next:

```
{
    "cachedir": "/home/osmdata/diff/",
    "connection": "postgis://postgres:123456@localhost:5432/geodb?sslmode=disable&prefix=NONE",
    "mapping": "/apps/imposm/mymap.json",
    "srid": 4326
}
```

I am getting error:
`[diff] unable to read last.state.txtstat /home/osmdata/diff/last.state.txt: no such file or directory`

What should include this file. If I do not want any "last state" and doing the fresh import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to use the wrong command, if a fresh import (e.g. empty table) of OSM PBF data is what you require. The *run* command is used to update existing OSM tables in PostgreSQL/PostGIS, and needs additional caching structure to be able to update via [OSM change files](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OsmChange) (e.g. *diffs*).

As stated in the [imposm import tutorial](https://imposm.org/docs/imposm3/latest/tutorial.html#importing), the general steps would be to import the data via read and write sequences like so (assuming *imposm3* based on your question, which is still under developement)

```
imposm3 import -config config.json -read yourdata.osm.pbf -write
```

which will import *yourdata.osm.pbf*, with the DB credentials and mapping file provided in your *config.json*.

Now, as stated in the [imposm updating tutorial](https://imposm.org/docs/imposm3/latest/tutorial.html#updating), to be able to use *OSM/diffs* to update an existing table (via the *use* command you provided), you will have to add the *-diff* parameter to the above import command like so

```
imposm3 import -config config.json -read yourdata.osm.pbf -write -diff -cachedir ./cache -diffdir ./diff
```

where you specify the directories for the general cache and the downloaded change files (*OSM/diffs*). This step includes the generation of the missing *last.state.txt* file in your example and enables you to use your *run* command on the already created OSM database.